# Why can't my yacc rule reduce here?

Tags: c, parsing, yacc

I am using YACC to do my compiler homework project. I found that my program could not get the syntax tree. So I printed it all out to see what is happening. According to my result, it seems that `ClassDecl` does not reduce to `ClassDeclList` here. But I can't understand why... can anyone help me out?

The sample input is:

```
   program ex11;
   class ab {
   }
```

It printed out as:

```
    programXXXX ex11ID
    semicon abID
    RBRACEnum 
    ClassBody ClassDecl ClassDecl1 Error!
```

The first three lines are messages I printed from my LEX file, to ensure that the characters are recognized correctly.

According to the information, the parser successfully reduces `{}` to `ClassBody` and `class ab {}` to `ClassDecl`. And then it does not reduce to `ClassDeclList`, is it because I am writing a left recursive grammar here?

This is the part of my YACC rule base for the inference:

```
    Program: PROGRAMnum IDnum SEMInum ClassDeclList
{printf("program"); $$ = MakeTree(ProgramOp,$4, MakeLeaf(IDNode,$2)); printtree($$,0);};

   ClassDeclList: ClassDecl 
{printf("ClassDeclList1");$$ = MakeTree(ClassOp,NullExp(),$1); printf("ClassDeclListend");};
                  |ClassDecl ClassDeclList 
{printf("ClassDeclList2");$$ = MakeTree(ClassOp,$2,$1); printf("ClassDeclList");};

    ClassDecl: CLASSnum IDnum ClassBody
{printf("ClassDecl");$$=MakeTree(ClassDefOp,$3,MakeLeaf(IDNode,$2)); printf("ClassDecl1");};
```

Comment: Can you show more of the code, for example the part where you print `Error!`?

Comment: Did your grammar compile without shift-reduce or reduce-reduce conflicts or other messages about useless rules and such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
| ClassDeclList ClassDecl
```

instead of

```
| ClassDecl ClassDeclList
```

?

I remember this fixing many problems when I used to use CUP.

Comment: yes, it worked, but I can't understand why? I thought that yacc would be more efficient using left recursive grammar?

Comment: I really will not help you here, it's been too long since I studied the theoretical compilers course. But this has to do with the mechanics of LR parsers. I used to teach the practical compilers course in the university, so this fix is out of expertise... not actual understanding :-D

Comment: This is nonsense. (Firstly @faz, your grammar is right recursive not left.)  I have a parser with right recursive rules along the pattern `LIST : ATOM | ATOM LIST;`. They work fine. Right recursive works because my actions do something like this `LIST : ATOM { $$ = cons($1, nil); };` and `LIST : ATOM LIST  { $$ = cons($1, $2); }`. Lisp-like lists are right-recursive, and so the grammar follows.

Comment: LALR(1) parsers can handle left and right recursive grammars just fine.

Comment: (But I should mention that the parsing stack depth is proportional to the size of the construct when you have a right recursive rule because the first reduction doesn't happen until you shift the whole construct.)